# Can I Use One view In a Django Project?

Tags: python, django

I´m new to web dev,
and I was wondering if it´s possible to make a website, that just need to present information of a company (HTML), in just one view.

Like rendering the entire bootstrap in one view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why would you want to do that.

You can use different `html` files which will be served as your website templates. You can also extend the files using a simple `base.html` file. This will help you if you want to open other links when people click on different links on the website.

See this example: https://github.com/singh1114/Djangosite/tree/master/duggal/webportal/templates/webportal.

For using this you have to know more about `views` and `urls`.

For making scrollable things, you need to know the concept of ids in HTML.

**For example**

*http://yoursite.com/#your_name* will try to find id *your_name* in the HTML. This way you can create scrollable things.

Comment: I want make one scrollable page, Clicking on a button just scrolls the page down or up to the respective area.

Comment: You must know the concept of id's in HTML. You can do that making the use of ids.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can serve your HTML code through a [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView).

So if your entire single page application sits in `home.html` you could definitely do this. But there is no point in using `Django` for only that purpose. You would rather want to serve your static HTML page from a classic web server like `nginx` or `apache`.